# Circular dependencies solutions?

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, autowired, circular-dependency

I recently upgraded to the latest Spring, and I'm now getting circular dependencies issues (I know the default is now no longer true to allow for circular dependencies) but even setting it to true still causes issues...  A perfect time to update my code:

My problem is this (where serviceA is autowired and has autowired service B, service B has autowired serviceC, service C has autowired serviceA):

```
  --->---serviceA
  |        |    
  |       \/
  |     serviceB
  |        |
  |       \/
  ---<---serviceC
```

The above (very simplified) scenario could be that ServiceA processes an event.  Service B checks the event -if it's not valid it sends it to ServiceC that creates a corrected event and resubmits to ServiceA....  I want the services to be singletons (and autowiring seems to provide the perfect answer with singletons in a context)

I've tried using autowired setters and lazy initialization but no luck and am still getting circular dependencies.  I know the documentation says to not use circular dependencies -which obviously I would prefer -but what is the best way to do this? Or can I not use autowiring and have to use a singleton pattern in serviceA to get it from within serviceC?  And in which case if I have any other autowiring in serviceA (such as the autowired serviceB!), I then have to apply a singleton pattern to serviceB, etc, etc (which would be a pain as wouldn't this negate the advantage of using autowiring?).

Answer (score 0):

Circular Dependencies are usually a sign of bad design and should be avoided, as you correctly mentioned. To improve your design you might want to get familiar with the SOLID principles. Especially, the Single Responsibility Principle.

From your description, ServiceB seems to be doing more than one thing. It validates your event and makes sure a ServiceC is called to created a new event. Instead you could have both ServiceB and ServiceC as dependencies of ServiceA. That would get rid of your circular dependency. Maybe this helps:

```
void process(Event event) {
  if(!serviceB.isValid(event)) {
    Event correctedEvent = serviceC.correctEvent(event);
    processValidEvent(correctedEvent);
  }
  processValidEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Just want to say thanks for the response.  Trying to work out if I should redesign (which would take some work -in retrospect having allowed circular dependencies being true wasn't a wise decision, but also something I wasn't aware of when I was using an earlier version of Spring.  I'm trying to work out the uses of lazy initialization, allowing circular dependencies to be true and whether or not I call a method on an autowired dependency which can affect things....

Answer (score 0):

Service C requires Service A but it not necessarily has to be a blocker for its instance creation. Instead of autowiring Service A in Service C, declare it as non-final field. A setter method to be exposed which could be called from `@PostConstruct` of Service A. Hence, service A is providing its instance to Service C after creation.

Ref: [Circular Dependencies in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring#4-use-postconstruct)